# Finding a lower and upper bound for the first eigenvalue of a Sturm Liouville problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the eigenvalue problem  $y''+\lambda (1+x^2)y=0$, $y(0)=y(1)=0$, 
I need to find a lower and upper bound for the first eigenvalue $\lambda_0$ (that fits the eigenfunction that has no zeros in $(0,1)$.)

My attempt- I know that there are infinitely many eigenvalues, in ascending order. So the lower bound is $0$, and the upper bound is $\lambda_1$. To find $\lambda_1$, I tried to find the eigenvalue that fits the case of one zero in the interval $(0,1)$.
This case leads to two zeroes of $y'$ in the interval $(0,1)$, and therefore one zero of $y''$ in $(0,1)$. Furthermore, I got that $y''=0$ in the same point that $y=0$.

This is the farthest I got. I didn't get $\lambda_1$.

Any ideas?